# Fixing onClick Closure Bug

Tags: javascript

[Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/) shows the following example:

**HTML**

`<button id="test">Click me!</button>`

**JavaScript**

```
var button = {
    clicked: false,
    click: function() {
        this.clicked = true;
        console.log("this:", this, "button.clicked?", button.clicked);
    }
};

var elem = document.getElementById("test");
elem.addEventListener("click", button.click, false);
```

When testing this out (http://jsfiddle.net/4hdQF/), `false` gets printed out.

After replacing the `console.log` statement with `...,`this.clicked?", this.clicked)`, it seems to work successfully - http://jsfiddle.net/YG8ST/.

The book mentions using `bind` to fix the first buggy app. But, is the replacement of `button.clicked` with `this.clicked` a valid fix? It seems to be since, when the `click` function gets called, it will use `this` to check if the current, in-context button was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using `this` is **not** the same as using `button`.  In the event handler, `this` will be bound to the DOM node, not that object.

If you're OK with having `this` be the DOM node, then it's fine to use it of course. However, that "clicked" property of the button object won't be affected by that code.

By setting up the event handler with a bound function:

```
elem.addEventListener("click", button.click.bind(button), false);
```

you ensure that `this` in the handler will be the button object, despite the fact that the runtime will try to invoke the handler the same way it always does. The function returned from `bind` basically overrides what the called did to set `this`.

Comment: so, to re-cap to make sure I understand, keep the code change I made, but use `bind` to ensure that the `button` object is `this` rather than the `DOM` node? it's interesting to me that the JavaScript code knows about the `button` node even though it's in HTML. Are certain DOM nodes keywords?

Comment: Well there are two answers: having an "id" attribute causes the browser to create a JavaScript-visible property on the `window` object. However, in this case the "click" happens in the context of the DOM, so it makes sense for the browser to provide you with a reference to the DOM when it invokes the event handler. That happens whether or not the element has an "id".